# Data grid Xamarin UWP issue - HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component

Tags: c#, android, uwp, xamarin.forms, xamarin.uwp

I am using the Xamarin.Forms.DataGrid data grid nuget package. When I run the application on an Android phone it will display the grid and data just fine. However, when I try to run the exact same code on UWP it will give me the following exception.

Error message:

> Message "System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.\r\n at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)\r\n at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)\r\n at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)\r\n at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.UWP.VisualElementRenderer`2.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)\r\n at Windows.UI.Xaml.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)\r\n at Xamarin.Forms.Plat" string.

It will display the empty grid and columns just fine in UWP if I comment out

`dgReceipts.ItemsSource = tempList;`

so I don't believe it could be a XAML issue.

Devices being used for testing are Samsung Galaxy S6  android 7.0 & Lumia 640

Any help is appreciated

XAML code

```
<dg:DataGrid x:Name="dgReceipts" RowHeight="70" HeaderHeight="50" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" HeaderBackground="#E0E6F8">
    <dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGridColumn Title="ID" Width="1*">
            <dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <ContentView>
                       <Label Text="{Binding Apar_ID}" VerticalOptions="Center" 
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
                    </ContentView>
                </DataTemplate>                                
            </dg:DataGridColumn.CellTemplate>

    </dg:DataGridColumn>
    </dg:DataGrid.Columns>
        <dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
            <dg:PaletteCollection>
                <Color>#F2F2F2</Color>
                <Color>#FFFFFF</Color>
            </dg:PaletteCollection>

        </dg:DataGrid.RowsBackgroundColorPalette>
</dg:DataGrid>
```

This is where I get the list of data

```
//Gets transactions for reports page
public async Task<List<x_Transactions>> GetReportTransactions()
{
    List<x_Transactions> transactions = await database.Table<x_Transactions>
    ().ToListAsync();
    return transactions;
}
```

And where it's set to the dg itemssource

```
public async Task FillGrid()
{
    List<x_Transactions> tempList;
    newList = await App.Database.GetReportTransactions();
    dgReceipts.ItemsSource = tempList;     
}
```

Comment: I have set item source of `DataGrid` with `dgReceipts.ItemsSource = new List<Item>()`, it works well. Have you tried to print `tempList`?

Comment: I can see that the correct amount of data is being returned in debug mode, and the fact it shows the correct data in Android also.

Comment: Please try to clean the solution and uninstall the app, rebuild the project again.

Comment: Still the same exception being given when I try to open the page on UWP. I will keep trying to fix it and if I don't I will post more of the code here later.

Comment: As you said it is not xaml issue. Have you tried to update your xamarin.forms version?

Comment: Yes, I have the latest version of Xamarin.Forms. I've also now set the data grid to .isvisible = false in the xaml. I added a button on the page which when clicked sets the .isvisible property to true. This works and displays the grid and data. Not how I want it but it will work for now.

Comment: Usual chimps for chumps .. clean, rebuild, update XF ... pus ca change

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use nested scrolling in `Xamarin.UWP` platform. `DataGrid` component uses `ListView` inside. It cannot have `ScrollView` parent.

Comment: Wow. That really really really stinks. Do you know of a ticket for this one in github or anything to fix this? Works fine in iOS and Android doesn't work here. Lots of cases where you want to have a list view that fully expands and stuff below that that scrolls.